# Both fade in and set height?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to both fade in and set the height of an element at the same time?

```
    if (scrollPosition > 50) {
    $("header").fadeIn("slow");
    $("header").css("height", "50px");
}
```

Comment: Fading happens over a time, when do you want the height change?

Comment: I think you can set the height of a HTML element then can apply fadeIn on it.

Comment: @Shomz would it be better to animate it? I guess it perhaps not possible to both fade in and set the height while it's fading in?

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do. What does "set the height at the same time" mean? Setting the height is instantaneous but fading takes time so you can't do it "at the same time". Do you want to animate the height from 0 to 50px instead?

Comment: Of course it's possible, even with plain CSS.

Comment: @Shomz How is that done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a CSS-only solution (using JS to toggle the class only):

```js
function toggle() {
  $('#d').toggleClass('show');
}
```

```css
#d {display: inline-block; height: 0; opacity: 0; width: 100px; background: green; transition: all 1s linear;vertical-align: top}
#d.show {height: 100px; opacity: 1}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="d"></div>
<br>
<button onclick="toggle()">Toggle</button>
```

Comment: Very nice, but there is a strange effect in the end when you toggle back. It's looks like a second toggle for the last bit?

Comment: It's because it's inline-block and there are no other elements to "hold" the height, so when it reaches the height of one row, it tends to stay there. Nothing to do with the animation itself.

Comment: @3D-kreativ happens with `inline-block` elements. You should try examples on your side.

Comment: Just fixed it with a simple `vertical-align: top`

Comment: Nice! I will try your code soon. Thanks for the help!